# Firebase Firestore error

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I try to add data to Firebase Firestore beta database and I get the following erre message:
*FAILED_PRECONDITION: The Cloud Firestore API is not enabled for the project*

Anyone can help on this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

if you got somethings like this...

```
Stream closed with status: 
code=FAILED_PRECONDITION, 
description=The Cloud Firestore API is not enabled for the project firebase-androchat, cause=null                                   
com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestoreException: 
FAILED_PRECONDITION: The Cloud Firestore API is not enabled for the project firebase-androchat
```

[image]

Probably you need to activate **Cloud Firestore Beta** at https://console.firebase.google.com

[image]

[image]

Into your project you have to select **Cloud Firestore Beta** and follow the instruction about rules!

Futhermore from the settings of your project you have to export the **"google-services.json"** file and copy it under **"app folder"**

[image]

Hope this help.

Comment: I was getting the same error and then after enabling Firebase on my project I got the error "This project contains a Cloud Datastore database and does not support Cloud Firestore API calls". However I never enabled Cloud Datastore, I simply enabled Firestore, and I don't use Datastore in my local code, nor did I enable it in the Console. Any ideas on workarounds?

Comment: I am also having the same issue/ error: (node:38500) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 2): Error: This project contains a Cloud Datastore database and does not support Cloud Firestore API calls

Answer (score 0):

Can you elaborate more about the problem you are facing?

You need to enable the Real Time Database which is in your Firebase console : https://console.firebase.google.com
in the top left of the screen of the Database section you will see the Cloud Firestore BETA which needs to be enabled.

For more information about how to connect and work on Enabling Offline Data

then this link can help you more https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/manage-data/enable-offline

  -

Comment: did you also add in the Project level gradle this: maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        } in the repositories section?

Comment: I think everything was setup and enabled correctly on the first time as well, but I just deleted the Firebase project, recreated it, enabled the email auth and Cloud Firestore and replaced the google-services.json file with the new one... and after that everything started to work correctly. At the first time when I enabled it there was only the headers (DATA, RULES, INDEXES, USAGE) and nothing under them on the Firebase Console... I think it was an internal error on the Cloud Firestore, it is still Beta.